# Basic usage of \pgfmathsetmacro causes trouble in Overleaf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm experiencing issues with Tikz figures in Overleaf. In particluar, the following usage of `\pgfmathsetmacro` causes a 'Missing control sequence inserted.':

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Test figure
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{x}{1}    
    \draw (-2,\x) -- (2,\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\draw` command reports a 'Undefined control sequence.', but I believe this is a consequence of the first error. The figure is properly generated, but the errors bother me.

What is stirring up the compiler?

Comment: Try with `\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1}`...

Comment: This issue might be easy to solve for experienced Ti*k*Z users, but I still think that the OP followed every rule for posting a question on this site and also provided a MWE. Thus, I don't see any reason to downvote this question.

Comment: How does it relate to Overleaf?

Comment: @wipet as it turns out it didn't relate to Overleaf. My understanding of the whole TeX ecosystem is rudimentary to say the least, so I added it for context just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the “undefined control sequence” error is a consequence of the first and most important “missing control sequence” error: the first argument to `\pgfmathsetmacro` ***must*** be a control sequence.

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1}
```

will do.

When you get errors, always start fixing from the first one.